# Consciousness and its relationship to Category Theory

Tags: logic, consciousness, meaning

Since consciousness is implicitly understood/used in the use of categories , could we consider it a "fundamental" functor ?
Category Theory is very general (covering/useful) to many fields now including mathematics, logic, philosophy, biology, music theory, sciences in general. See j-paine.org/dobbs/why_be_interested_in_categories.html?

Comment: Can you say more about how consciousness is used in Category theory? The subject of consciousness is not part of math class nor of any exposition of Category theory that I'm aware of. Except to the extent that one needs to remain awake during class as the professor is chasing diagrams.

Comment: I am entertaining the idea of adding "consciousness concept" to the mathematics of Category Theory. Category Theory is a good place to start. Some physicists are attempting to explain consciousness within the framework of physics.

Comment: Isn't it a long way from "I am entertaining the idea of adding "consciousness concept" to the mathematics of Category Theory." to "Since consciousness is implicitly understood/used in the use of categories ...?" Should you reword your question?

Comment: Like, can consciousness be considered a functor (or metafunctor) in Category Theory.

Comment: CATEGORIES AND FUNCTORS FOR THE STRUCTURAL-PHENOMENOLOGICAL MODELING         http://www.racai.ro/media/Categories.pdf

Comment: I read the paper you linked to there. There appears to me to be no link between the category theory and the philosphy content, despite them being interspersed liberally. In particular, neither the morphisms, the identity morphisms nor the composition seem to have actually been defined in a way recognisable to a category theorist. Similarly for the functors. The phrase "natural transformation" has been used without reference to a pair of functors nor to the laws such must obey. It's difficult for me not to conclude that the author hasn't understood the fundamentals of category theory, sorry.

Comment: The central problem is that mathematicians (and logicians) use language differently to most folk, with zero flexibility in the meaning of a term. If you add flexibility to such a general definition you end up with nothing at all.

Comment: Category Theory as the Language of Consciousness http://www.noeticadvancedstudies.us/Amoroso24.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> Since consciousness is implicitly understood/used in the use of categories

None of the books and papers I've seen in Category Theory mentions consciousness. One could say that one needs to be consciousness to *do* mathematics or to comprehend it; but this goes for any project. However, MacClane wrote in the Introduction to [Categories for the Working Mathematician](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+theory)

> Now the discovery of ideas as general as these is chiefly the willingness to make a brash or speculative abstraction, in this case supported by the pleasure of purloining words from the philosophers: “Category” from Aristotle and Kant, “Functor” from Carnap (Logische Syntax der Sprache), and “natural transformation” from then current informal parlance

Kant uses his theory of consciousness to buttress [Aristotles theory of categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being); for example early on his *Critique of Pure Reason* he states that Space & Time are (categories) in the mind because they are the very conditions by which we experience. These categories are thus phenomenological (the name of which explicitly displays both the subjective character of say space as phenomena, and its objective character as theorised by Physics as logical).

The introduction of mathematics into the human sciences tends to be a minority position; for example Lacan introduces topology into psychology; had he been simply known for only this it seems safe to say that there would be no such field as Lacanian psychology; his importance lay in the re-invigoration of Freudian psychology by the introduction of the Mirror Stage; one might say, on the basis of intellectual history, that the same may go for the explicit introduction of category theory into the theory of consciousness.